# .Plist array generating random strings into UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, plist

I have created an .Plist titled PhobiaList.plist.
Im unsure of how i would implement the plist so that when button1 is pressed it will show a random entry into lable1?

Comment: Do you mean a random entry from the plist?

Comment: yes. and then to display the random entry to my uilabel

Comment: ok. i hope my answer below can help you. otherwise just ask what you did't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have an array stored in your plist. Then you can generate a random number between 0 and `[theArray count]`.

```
NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [theArray count];
```

Select the string by calling.

```
NSString* yourRandomString = [theArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
```